# How do I return only one element from at a time and and int from range in python for loop

Tags: python

So I tried using this block of code but what it does is it puts the items from resources index 0 and 1 into both variables on the first iteration. I want a way to where resources will map to alph and range will map to i. Is this possible in python?

```py
resources = ["a", "b", "c"]
for alph, i in resources, range(len(resources)):
     print(alph)
     if i == 2:
         print(2)
```

I'm basically looking for something similar to golang's range where you would type

```golang
resources := ["a", "b", "c"]
for incrementer, alph := range resources {
     fmt.Print(alph)
     if i == 2 {
         fmt.Print(2)
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```html
resources = ["a", "b", "c"]
for key, value in enumerate(resources):
     if value == "a":
         print(str(key) + "-" + value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use python's built-in [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function.

```
resources = ["a", "b", "c"]
for i, alph in enumerate(resources):
    ...
```